# Parser Error when trying to debug web service application

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, web-services, .net-3.5

In one of my solutions's I can't seem to have a ASP.Net web service application project - I've always used them successfully in the past. Even now I can create another solution and add a project of this type and run it. However the solution that I currently want to add it to won't run it, I get the following error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not create type 'IntegrationService.Service1'.
Source Error: 

Line 1:  <%@ WebService Language="VB" CodeBehind="Service1.asmx.vb" Class="IntegrationService.Service1" %>

Source File: /Service1.asmx    Line: 1 

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4952; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4955
```

I'm not doing anything special here and there are many similar questions, but they all differ slightly and don't appear to relate as I'm not trying to deploy etc.

Anyone know why this is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who runs into this problem:

For some reason in the Solution Properties screen - Configuration Properties - Configuration, the project I added didn't have the build check box ticked.

I don't know why this happened - I don't seem to have this "Configuration Properties" option on other solutions.